# Query: How can enumerate rows based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

Having the following table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Data
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    Code VARCHAR(10),
    Fee VARCHAR(3),
    AValue DECIMAL(10, 4)
)
-- DELETE FROM #Data
INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES
('A001', '001', 100), ('A001', '002', 200), ('A001', '003', -50), ('A001', '004', -250), ('A001', '005', 340), ('A001', '006', 500), ('A001', '007', 600)
```

I need to get the following result (an ordered sequence based if Value is still positive or negative):

```
Code    Fee Value      Row
A001    001 100.0000   P1
A001    002 200.0000   P1
A001    003 -50.0000   N1
A001    004 -250.0000  N1
A001    005 340.0000   P2
A001    006 500.0000   P2
A001    007 600.0000   P2
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT Code, Fee, AValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code, (CASE WHEN AValue > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ORDER BY Fee) 'nRow',
FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code, Fee, CASE WHEN AValue > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ORDER BY Fee), CASE WHEN AValue > 0 THEN 'POS00' ELSE 'NEG00' END)
FROM #Data
```

But it returns:

```
Code    Fee Value      Row
A001    001 100.0000   P1
A001    002 200.0000   P1
A001    003 -50.0000   N1
A001    004 -250.0000  N1
A001    005 340.0000   P1
```

Comment: What is the logic here? You don't explain it. If I am guessing correctly at what the logic is, what happens when `value` has the value `0`?

Comment: @Larnu I need to create groups sorted according to whether Value is still positive or negative.

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, but it is tricky.  Assuming you have no `0` values, then `sign()` is your friend.

Here is an approach that uses the fact that the difference of row numbers is constant when values on adjacent rows should be combined:

```
SELECT Code, Fee, AValue, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sign(avalue) ORDER BY seqnum - seqnum_2) as num
FROM (SELECT d.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code, sign(avalue) ORDER BY fee) as seqnum_2,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY fee) as seqnum
      FROM Data d
     ) d
ORDER BY Code, Fee;
```

You can incorporate this into your string using `CONCAT()` or whatever.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8bbff5ba5c9edda78b39c9bd4541d38f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I completely forgot there was a `SIGN` function

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a blind guess, but perhaps this is what you are after:

````sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT Code,
           Fee,
           AValue,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Fee) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Avalue > 0 THEN 1 WHEN Avalue < 0 THEN -1 END ORDER BY Fee) AS Grp
    FROM #Data)
SELECT Code,
       Fee,
       AValue,
       CONCAT(CASE WHEN Avalue > 0 THEN 'P' WHEN Avalue < 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Z' END, 
              DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Avalue > 0 THEN 1 WHEN Avalue < 0 THEN -1 END ORDER BY Grp)) AS Row
FROM Grps
ORDER BY Fee;```
````